# Cambiar color de background de JButton inhabilitado

Tags: java, java-swing, color, jbutton

Estoy tratando de cambiar el color de fondo que tienen los JButtons cuando están inhabilitados. Probé con el UIManager buscando los defaults del mismo [aquí](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/) y lo que más se parece es *Button.disabledText*, pero como su nombre lo indica: sólo cambia el color de las letras del botón cuando el mismo está inhabilitado. El color de background es el mismo.
Si cambio el color de background de los botones en general usando *Button.background*, el color de los botones habilitados e inhabilitados es el mismo, y sólo se diferencian por el color del texto.

¿Alguna ayuda?

Answer (score 1):

No hay color para agregar a el botón cuando esta en disable, inspeccionando el código de Java con Eclipse vi que solo están estos 3 colores en MetalButtonUI:

```
protected Color focusColor;
protected Color selectColor;
protected Color disabledTextColor;
```

Obviamente los que se pueden cambiar con el UIManager.

Hice una búsqueda en google y di con esto https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5751311/creating-a-custom-button-in-java-with-jbutton/5755124#5755124

Entonces la solución que tuve es crear una clase que extienda de MetalButtonUI y sobre escribir el metodo `update()`, ya que lo que hace este método es comprobar si el botón esta activo únicamente, entonces tenes que sobrescribir este método y decirle a Java que haga lo que ya hace pero que compruebe ahora si el botón esta deshabilitado para agregarle el color que desee, de esta manera:

```
public class UIButtonMod extends MetalButtonUI {

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g, JComponent c) {
        super.update(g, c);
    
        if(!c.isEnabled()) {
            c.setBackground(Color.RED); // tu color
        }
    
    }

}
```

Bueno esto funciona, programe una tarea para que suceda después de 1 segundo y que agregase el `setEnabled(false);`, el botón si que cambia de color, el otro problema que sucede es que hay que asignarle este nuevo UI al botón, por lo tanto debe estar ya creado.

Cada que crees un botón deberías establecer `setUI(new UIButtonMod());` o sino tener un **template** de JButton que usaras para crear todos los botones:

```
public JButton getTempButton(String text) {
    JButton button = new JButton(text);
    button.setUI(new UIButtonMod());
    return button;
}
```

Esto lo digo porque no puede hacer funcionar el `UIManager.put("ButtonUI", UIButtonMod.class.getName());` por alguna razón ni lo registra.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, voy a tratar de experimentar un poco con esto y ver si llego a buen puerto. Saludos.